# Variable scope for different sessions in PHP

Tags: php, variables, scope

I've just started PHP developement and I would like to know a bit more about variables scope.

I ***know*** about the scope ***inside the script***. I just want to know, how variables are treated between ***different users***. Let's say I have a class :

```php
class SomeClass {
    public static $myVar = 0;

    public static function doSomethingToMyVar(){
        // $myVar gets manipulated
    }
}
```

***NOTE***: I know it's an awful design, so it's just for showing an example of my question.

Now my question is: if `user A` uses the page so that `doSomethingToMyVar` is called, does `user B` get modified value of `$myVar`? I mean, do different users share static variables or PHP gives seperate sets of variables for each user?

Comment: No - each time a web page is visited it creates an entirely new instance of the application which knows nothing about any others, the web is stateless. It doesn't even know about previous pages visited by the *same user* - that's why cookies were invented.

Comment: PHP is a stateless language. The request starts, the response is sent and the script dies. There's no sharing of anything in between requests. They all start fresh.

Comment: You can use a file or database for it :)

Comment: Thank you, everyone. That's all I needed!